# Magento 2: Hide other shipping methods when free shipping is available

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, free-shipping

I charge my customers flat rate for shipping and I also offer free shipping for orders that are above certain amount. At the moment, customers who qualify for free shipping will also have paid shipping option shown, which may confuse some customers. Does anyone know if there's a way to hide other shipping methods when free shipping method is available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Remove "Free Shipping" configuration because you don't need it (you already have "Cart Price Rules").

When your customer qualifies for free shipping it happens based on "Flat Rate" not in "Free Shipping".

Answer (score 9):

Use the extension [ShippingTweaks](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.ShippingTweaks).

Comment: Hi @vitalli is this module will help me to hide shipping methods based on my product attribute?

Answer (score 6):

Write a plugin to disable flat rate shipping method when free shipping is actually enabled based on cart sub total.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate">
        <plugin name="disable-flatrate" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Carrier\Flatrate" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Write a Model class to process sub total validation.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Carrier;

class Flatrate
{

    const XML_PATH_FREE_SHIPPING_SUBTOTAL = "carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal";

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function afterCollectRates(\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate $flatRate, $result)
    {
        $scopeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES;

        // Get MOA value from system configuration.
        $freeShippingSubTotal = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_FREE_SHIPPING_SUBTOTAL, $storeScope, $scopeId);

        // Get cart subtotal from checkout session.
        $baseSubTotal = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getBaseSubtotal();

        // Validate subtoal should be empty or Zero.
        if(!empty($baseSubTotal) && !empty($freeShippingSubTotal)) {

            if($baseSubTotal >= $freeShippingSubTotal) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @maniprakash where i need to create di.xml ?

Comment: Romba nandri its working fine.

Comment: how to hide shipping methods based on product / cart item attribute?

Comment: can u help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/327438/magento-2-how-to-display-shipping-methods-sort-order-by-price

Answer (score 4):

etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement">
    <plugin name="vendor_module_plugin_model_quote_shipping_method_management" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\ShippingMethodManagement"  disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

Plugin/Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php

```
public function afterEstimateByAddress($shippingMethodManagement, $output)
{
    return $this->filterOutput($output);
}

public function afterEstimateByExtendedAddress($shippingMethodManagement, $output)
{
    return $this->filterOutput($output);
}

public function afterEstimateByAddressId($shippingMethodManagement, $output)
{
    return $this->filterOutput($output);
}

private function filterOutput($output)
{
    $free = [];
    foreach ($output as $shippingMethod) {
        if ($shippingMethod->getCarrierCode() == 'freeshipping' && $shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == 'freeshipping') {
            $free[] = $shippingMethod;
        }
    }

    if ($free) {
        return $free;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Hi can u help me on this please https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/327438/magento-2-how-to-display-shipping-methods-sort-order-by-price

Answer (score 1):

in response to @Nagaraju and hoping  to help to anyone.

The di.xml can be created in any module you have, or if you dont know how and where:

***app/code/My_Vendor/MyModule/etc/di.xml*** -> here is where you put the code of @maniprakash

then you should create the class in:

***app/code/My_Vendor/MyModule/Model/Flatrate*** -> and paste the class code of @maniprakash

Just remember to change the path in type tag on the di.xml

```
<plugin name="disable-flatrate" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Carrier\Flatrate" sortOrder="1" />
```

the path **must match where your Model class is it**. in my example should be

```
<plugin name="disable-flatrate" type="My_Vendor\MyModule\Model\Flatrate" sortOrder="1" />
```

AND that's it!  hope it helps! and thanks to @manipakrash , it helps me! =)

Answer (score 0):

Hide free shipping on checkout

Vendor/magento/Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-item.html

```
<!-- ko if: method.carrier_code !== 'freeshipping' -->
<tr class="row"
click="element.selectShippingMethod">
<td class="col col-method">
    <input type="radio"
           class="radio"
           ifnot="method.error_message"
           ko-checked="element.isSelected"
           ko-value="method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code"
           attr="'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code,
                'checked': element.rates().length == 1 || element.isSelected" />
    <span class="label"></span>
</td>
<td class="col col-price">
    <each args="element.getRegion('price')" render="" />
</td>
<td class="col col-carrier"
    attr="'id': 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
    text="method.carrier_title" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate">
        <plugin name="disable-flaterate" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier\Flatrate" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier\Flatrate.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier;

class Flatrate{   

    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate $tablerate,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->tablerate = $tablerate;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function afterCollectRates(\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate $Flatrate, $result, $request)
    {   
        $regionId = '';
        if($request && $request->getDestRegionId()) {
            $regionId = $request->getDestRegionId();
        }

        $resTableRate = $this->tablerate->collectRates($request);
        foreach ($resTableRate->getAllRates() as $rate) {
            if ($rate->getMethod()) {
                 return false;
            }
        }
    
        $base_subtotal_incl_tax = $request->getData('base_subtotal_incl_tax');
        if($base_subtotal_incl_tax > 50) {
            return false;
        }
        $items = $request->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
            $sku = $item->getSku();
        }
        return $result;
    } 
}
```