# Magento 2: How to hide shipping method on front end for custom logic

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, custom-shipping-method

Hi I have create custom shipping method. I have enabled it from back end. Now I want show this only if product custom attribute match some conditions.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103175/magento-2-hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available/354110#354110

Answer (score 2):

It's your custom shipping method which have **collectRates** method in somewhere in model folder ex. for Flatrate shipping method collectRates method is located at Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }
    if($customeProductConditionFalse)
       {
        return false;
       }
    ........
}
```

In this method you can check your condition for product custom attribute match or not and

```
return false;
```

to disable shipping method

Comment: i can add product attribute condition but what is the code for disable shipping method.

Comment: you need to send return false to disable it

Comment: Is this working for you? I do not want to disable shipping method. But I want to hide the shipping method on some product custom option condition.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @PratikKamani Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create `etc/di.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface">
        <plugin name="hide_show_shipping_methods" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create `Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationPlugin.php`.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote\Api;

use Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface;

class ShipmentEstimationPlugin
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function aroundEstimateByExtendedAddress(
        ShipmentEstimationInterface $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address
    ) {
        $shippingMethods = $proceed($cartId, $address);
        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            foreach ($shippingMethods as $key => $shippingMethod) {
                //Replace 'freeshipping' with your shipping method which you want to hide
                if ($shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == 'freeshipping') {
                    unset($shippingMethods[$key]);
                }
            }

            return $shippingMethods;
        }
    }
}
```

It will work for you.

Comment: i tried your plugin for all user but its not works

Comment: What issue you face?