# Magento 2 : Prevent custom shipping method to be displayed

Tags: checkout, shipping, multistore, shipping-methods, stores

Is there any way I can check for specific store id & based on that prevent shipping method to be displayed?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Create etc/di.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface">
        <plugin name="hide_show_shipping_methods" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationPlugin.php.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote\Api;

use Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface;

class ShipmentEstimationPlugin
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, 
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function aroundEstimateByExtendedAddress(
        ShipmentEstimationInterface $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address
    ) {
        $shippingMethods = $proceed($cartId, $address);
        if ($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId() == "<store_id>") {
            foreach ($shippingMethods as $key => $shippingMethod) {
                //Replace 'freeshipping' with your shipping method which you want to hide
                if ($shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == 'freeshipping') {
                    unset($shippingMethods[$key]);
                }
            }

            return $shippingMethods;
        }
    }
}
```

It will work for you.

This is a modification of this [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/274556/77554) as it work for me

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer.
I am not sure if this solution works "cart" mutation
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/cart.html
I am using graphql