# Magento 2.3: How to hide only free shipping method if postal code 2nd index is 0

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, jquery

I want to hide only the free shipping method on the checkout page if the postal code 2nd index is 0. I tried this but it's not removing from shipping methods.

```
require(['mage/url', 'jquery','domReady!' ,'jquery/ui'],function(url , $)  {


$("[name='postcode']").live('change',function(){
        postCode = $("[name='postcode']").val();
         // console.log(postCode);
             postCode = postCode.slice(1,2);
             console.log(postCode);

        if(postCode == 0){

            // $('.checkout-shipping-method').hide();
             jQuery("#label_method_freeshipping_freeshipping").closest('.row').hide();
           // console   .log('Hellow');     


        }
        else{
            // $('.checkout-shipping-method').show();
            $('#label_method_freeshipping_freeshipping').closest('.row').show();
            $("#message").hide();

        }
    });


    });
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103175/magento-2-hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available. In this reference hide flat rate shipping method based on total. same way you can make plugin of free shipping method and based on postal code you can hide free shipping method